# Unpickling object of type X in the __new__ method of class X calls __init__ on returning the unpickled object, why?

Tags: python, caching, constructor, pickle, initializer

I have an object that will be cached after it's first use. I will do this using the cPickle module. If the module is already cached, when I try to instantiate the object the next time around (in another process) I would like to use the cached object. Following is my basic structure:

```
import cPickle
class Test(object):
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if name == 'john':
            print "using cached object"
            with open("cp.p", "rb") as f:
                obj = cPickle.load(f)
                print "object unpickled"
                return obj
        else:
            print "using new object"
            return super(Test, cls).__new__(cls, name)
    def __init__(self, name):
        print "calling __init__"
        self.name = name
        with open("cp.p", "wb") as f:
            cPickle.dump(self, f)
```

The problem is that when I unpickle the cached object in the `__new__` method it calls the `__init__` and reinitializes everything. Interestingly it seems like the `__init__` isn't called after the unpickling, but rather when the unpickled object is returned. I have added a print statement that shows this ("object unpickled").

I have a hacky workaround by adding the following check to the `__init__`:

```
intiailzed = False
...
...
def __init__(self, name):
    if not self.intialized:
        self.initialized = True
        # Rest of the __init__ here
```

As well as a class attribute called initialized, but this is obviously not ideal.

Any insight into how to suppress the `__init__` method (or why it's being called at all) would be appreciated.

Edit: Based on feedback here is my new proposed solution:

```
class Test(object):
    def __new__(cls, name=None):
        print "calling __new__"
        if name == 'john':
            print "using cached object"
            with open("cp.p", "rb") as f:
                obj = cPickle.load(f)
            print "object unpickled"
            return obj
        else:
            print "using new object"
            obj = super(Test, cls).__new__(cls, name)
            obj.initialize(name)
            return obj

    def __init__(self, name):
        pass

    def initialize(self, name):
        print "calling __init__"
        self.name = name
        with open("cp.p", "wb") as f:
            cPickle.dump(self, f)
```

Comment: Per the docs, ["If __new__() returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will be invoked"](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

Comment: Per [Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__), "the immutable types have a dummy `__init__`, while the mutable types have a dummy `__new__`." Unless you have a good reason (and I don't know of any) your classes should follow the same pattern too.

Comment: This was just a simplified generalization of what I actually have to get my point across easier, the conditions are much different. Thanks for the tip though, although it's probably not a bad thing to let it fail considering if my condition is met and the file doesn't exist I'd want it to fail.

Comment: I was trying to solve a similar problem. I tried your way, but I ran into another issue. When my object is unpickled, pickle creates the object using the `__new__` method, which goes to unpickle the object, which calls the `__new__` method and goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: My work-around is putting an `if-else` statement at the beginning of `__init__()` which evaluates `hasattr(self, 'some_attr_assigned_in_original_instantiation')`.  If `True` then the object already has this `attr` which means we are dealing with an unpickled object and `__init__()` should effectively exit with a `pass` statement.  If `False` then we are dealing with the original object instantiation and should continue creating `attr`s as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj = Test(name)` works like this:

```
obj = Test.__new__(Test, name)
if isinstance(obj, Test):
    obj.__init__(name)
```

Since the unpickled object returned from `Test.__new__(Test, name)` is an instance of `Test`, its `__init__` method gets called. It doesn't matter whether the object came from `super(Test, cls).__new__` or unpickling.

To avoid problems like this, classes that override `__new__` should generally return completely-initialized objects from `__new__` and not define `__init__`. Their subclasses should also follow this rule.

Comment: I added a solution based on your suggestion, could you take a look and give me some feedack. It seems to work how I want it to.

Comment: @J.Doe: Yeah, that works, although I wouldn't have `initialize` say `calling __init__`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, and yea I just hastily copied everything into `initialize`, I wouldn't even have those print statements normally.