# Load class instance from pickle file during instantiation with HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

Tags: python, pickle, instantiation

#### Goal

- When I create an instance of ClassA:

  - if a pickle file exists, then load the instance from pickle file
  - if a pickle file does not exist, then create the instance from scratch
- use pickle HIGHEST_PROTOCOL.

#### Fail

Someone [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458221/unpickling-object-of-type-x-in-the-new-method-of-class-x-calls-init-on-r#comment86463041_36458221) the same problem in a comment.
The problem is also described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672075/why-isnt-pickle-calling-new-like-the-documentation-says/36672316#36672316): if protocol > 1, then pickle calls `__new__` during loading, which creates an infinite recursion.

```
# module_a.py
import os
import pickle
# import dill as pickle

save_path = r'C:\tests\pickle_tests\saved_instance_of_a.pkl'

def load(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

def dump(x, path):
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(
            x, f,
            protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

class ClassA:
    def __new__(cls):
        print('__new__ called')

        if os.path.isfile(save_path):
            print('The saved pickle exists: loading from file.')
            instance = load(save_path)

        else:
            print('The saved pickle does not exist: creating.')
            instance = super(ClassA, cls).__new__(cls)

        return instance

    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__ called')
        if not os.path.isfile(save_path):
            self.my_dict = {'pi': 3.14}
            dump(self, save_path)
```

```
# myprogram.py
import os
import module_a

if __name__ =='__main__':
    instance_a = module_a.ClassA()
    print(instance_a.my_dict)
```

First run OK (creating instance from scratch):

```
$ python myprogram.py
__new__ called
The saved pickle does not exist: creating.
__init__ called
{'pi': 3.14}
```

Second run fail (loading instance from pickle):

```
$ python myprogram.py
__new__ called
The saved pickle exists: loading from file.
__new__ called
The saved pickle exists: loading from file.
__new__ called
The saved pickle exists: loading from file.
__new__ called
The saved pickle exists: loading from file.
__new__ called
...
  File "C:\tests\pickle_tests\module_a.py", line 19, in __new__
    print('__new__ called')
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

#### Current workaround

The code above works if I replace
`protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`
by
`protocol=0`
but I do not want to use protocol 0 (or 1). I want to use `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`.

First run OK:

```
$ python myprogram.py
__new__ called
The saved pickle does not exist: creating.
__init__ called
{'pi': 3.14}
```

Second run OK:

```
$ python myprogram.py
__new__ called
The saved pickle exists: loading from file.
__init__ called
{'pi': 3.14}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pickle calling `__new__` is what is causing a the problem, a simple workaround to allow use of `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` would be for you to **not** use it yourself and do everything in the `__init__()` method.

Here's a way to do that:

`myprogram.py`:

```
import os
import module_a

if __name__ =='__main__':
    instance_a = module_a.ClassA()
    print(instance_a.my_dict)
```

`module_a.py`:

```
import os
import pickle

SAVE_PATH = r'C:\tests\pickle_tests\saved_instance_of_a.pkl'

def load(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

def dump(x, path):
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(x, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__ called')
        if os.path.isfile(SAVE_PATH):
            print('  loading from pickle file.')
            self.__dict__ = load(SAVE_PATH)
        else:
            print('  creating from scratch.')
            self.my_dict = {'pi': 3.14}
            dump(self.__dict__, SAVE_PATH)
```

Comment: Thanks @Martineau. I thought I needed `__new__` because `self = load(SAVE_PATH)` was failing in `__init__`. In your solution, instead of dump/load the instance itself, you dump/load its `__dict__`, I did not think of it. I'm pondering whether [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is sufficient to capture everything the saved instance was made of (`__dict__` = "A dictionary or other mapping object used to store an object’s (writable) attributes")? If yes, then that is a good solution.

Comment: `self = load(SAVE_PATH)` doesn't work because all it does is assign a different value to the local variable name `self` (i.e. it does not do what you think). This trick would not work for immutable classes which *must* have a `__new__()` method (like a subclass of `tuple` for example).